# How to record screen and broadcast to smart TV in the same wifi network on ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, broadcast, replaykit

I used Broadcast Extension for screen recording on ios device. But I don't know how to stream ios device screen to smart TV on same wifi network?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device to the same Wi-Fi network as your Apple TV or AirPlay 2-compatible smart TV.
Find the video that you want to stream.
Tap AirPlay . In some apps, you might need to tap a different icon first.* In the Photos app, tap Share  , then tap AirPlay  .
Choose your Apple TV or AirPlay 2-compatible smart TV.
To stop streaming, tap AirPlay  in the app that you're streaming from, then tap your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Technique:

- write your screen record as video format to device's storage.
- start a hls server on your app and enable streaming url to video's data.
- beam the hls url to your TV media player.

Your TV media player will play the screen record.
You can do a research with `HaishinKit` for detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have written content to HTTPStream (CMSampleBuffer), I use this URL and cast to TV, it doesn't work.

```
let url = URL.init(string: "abc.m38u")!
let mediaInfoBuilder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder.init(contentURL: url)
mediaInfoBuilder.streamType = GCKMediaStreamType.buffered
mediaInfoBuilder.contentID = mediaURL.absoluteString
mediaInfoBuilder.contentType = mediaURL.mimeType()
mediaInfoBuilder.hlsSegmentFormat =.TS
mediaInfoBuilder.hlsVideoSegmentFormat=.MPEG2_TS
//mediaInfoBuilder.streamDuration = .infinity
```

The errors is :
-Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=30 "Media failed to load" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Media failed to load, gck_detailed_error_code=301}
-[GCKMediaControlChannel didReceiveTextMessage:] - Received unexpected error: INVALID_REQUEST
-[GCKMediaQueue request:didFailWithError:] - error fetching queue item IDs: Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=4 "Invalid request" UserInfo={gck_error_reason=INVALID_MEDIA_SESSION_ID, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid request, gck_custom_data=INVALID_MEDIA_SESSION_ID}

How can I fix that.

In addition, using "HLS" content will be delayed 5 to 10 seconds compared to iPhone.
Besides using "HLS", is there any other way?

Thanks.